# What can cause the Windows scheduler to ignore a high priority thread when CPU cores are available?

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-7, windows-10, scheduler

I have a multi-threaded application in which one of the threads has a time-critical job.  This time-critical thread is set to 'time critical' priority when it is launched.  Additionally, the other threads in the application have a processor affinity mask set so that this time-critical thread always has full access to eight CPU cores (out of 12 total across two Xeons).  No other applications are running on the server (other than whatever services Windows runs on its own).

Still, even with all these precautions, I record events where this time critical thread does not run for 80-100ms at a time.  My logging shows that it sometimes halts mid-task, and picks up again after the 80-100ms time lapse.

**My question is:** what could be causing these 80-100ms thread blackouts and/or how do I figure out what is causing them?

Some other possibly relevant information:

- The blackouts strongly correlate with heavy activity on the *other* application threads, but I am monitoring the CPU usage charts in the Resource Monitor and can see that the CPUs dedicated to the time critical task are far less than 100% (but the 4 that have full access are usually 100% during this time)
- There is also heavy network activity during these peak performance periods in which the blackouts tend to occur.
- The time critical task is interfacing with a piece of hardware via PCIe communication, but the 'blackout' events do not necessarily occur when talking to this device.
- When everything is working properly, the time critical thread only spends around 1-2ms doing work and then waits for around 30ms in a busy loop.
- The time critical task does share a resource with some other threads, but it is protected via spinlock and logging indicates blackouts are not occurring when waiting for a lock.  Also, I can see these other threads are not holding on to the spinlock for more than a few microseconds.
- Changing the application priority to 'HIGH' via the task manager does not improve performance
- I have test servers running Win7 and Win10, and both show the problem.

Comment: I can't find the source right now, but I recall that affinity masks are not something you want to use in production. I am otherwise uninformed though.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NH1Tta7purM) is a very good cppcon talk about high frequency trading which has many of these same characteristics.  The presenters advice might help you out.  One main take away is that time critical code should run on it's own CPU, or even better it's own machine so you have control of the processor.

Comment: @MaxLanghof We aren't running with affinity masks in production, but I'm experimenting with them now to see if they offer improvements with this issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver that talk seems interesting, but the presenter is interested in latencies an order of manitude shorter than my situation.  100ms is a LONG time to a processor, and I can't yet explain why this happens.  Also, I have dedicated multiple CPU cores to this critical thread, so CPU availability seems to not be the problem.

Comment: How are you controlling the timing of the critical loop?  (sleep, condition variable, etc.)

Comment: @ttemple I was using a semaphore implemented with condition variable, but I recently switched to an atomic<uint32_t> semaphore loop to see if it improved latency.  It did improve response latency, but didn't improve the 100ms blackout problem.

Comment: If you want zero jitter you must a) use lock-free data structures i.e. **no locks of any kind** and **also** b) make sure the hardware is appropriately sized i.e. no swapping, no paging out code, disk queue never exceeds 1 and averages less than 0.1, probably never exceeding 50% cpu at **peak** loads.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a number of tests over the past few days, and was able to collect some interesting data, which I will summarize below.

1. The problem pretty much never occurs when the CPUs are largely idle
2. I can easily cause a failure by blasting the CPU from another process that simply consumes it using many threads
3. I thought I could reduce the problem by limiting most threads via process affinity masks and leaving the time-critical threads on their own dedicated CPUs.  However, it turned out that this was not a complete solution because there exist some shared locks (to pass information and also logging facilities) that caused contention issues.  The high contention, but low priority threads that briefly hold a critical lock would be put to sleep while holding the lock, leaving my high priority threads (on idle cpus, mind you) waiting.
4. By far, the most interesting test I ran was to take a particular Windows 7 test system with a high failure rate and I installed a fresh copy Windows 10 on the same exact hardware and ran the exact same software.  This enormously reduced the failure rate given the same exact operating conditions.

Ultimately, I believe the problem comes down to Windows not doing a good job of handling 1) thread priorities, in general and 2) priority inversion issues especially.  Surprisingly, Windows 10 appears to handle these issues substantially better than Windows 7.

Microsoft has a brief [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/priority-inversion) about how the OS handles priority inversion, but it appears that when the CPUs are heavily loaded with multiple threads this strategy is insufficient to prevent long delays on the critical threads, especially with Windows 7.